# What is the suggested level before entering Volskygge in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So what's the suggested level for an attempt on Volskygge?
 Just wondering, because I'd heard that once you pass a certain point, you'd have to revert to get out without completing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished that one and yes, like several other dungeons I've found so far, there is a point of no return, much to my annoyance. I was about level 22, a one-handed/heavy-armor type with a trusty companion. The last two encounters were quite challenging. The difficulty slider is always your friend.

I'd suspect that mid-teens is probably the earliest you'd like to try it depending on your build.

Answer (score 3):

I passed the point of no return, and I was level 18/19. Wasn't prepared for the last battles, so became invisible and walked around the Overlord, went outside, traded some stuff, and returned through the same door I left, Lydia, bless her, was still there and I defeated the overlord

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which level would be appropriate but I have just finished this dungeon at about level 23 with my archery at 60 as my primary damage dealing skill. The only problem I had was the last boss which is an elemental thing that flies around. I was just able to break line of sight with trees and fire off my arrows. I'm not sure if this is required to clear but you probably want the loot.

Comment: It's one of the Dragon Priests - Volsung.